# How do I make my other operations work properly?

Tags: java, javafx, multiplication, subtraction

I have built a simple calculator and i am trying to get it to multiply and subtract correctly as i already have addition and division working. my problem is i cant figure out why multiplication and subtraction wouldn't be working.Here is what i have.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.stage.*;
    import javafx.scene.*;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

    public class JavaFxCalc extends Application implements          
     EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    Button [] numButtons;

    Insets insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    TextField resultsTextField;

    HBox topRow,middleRow,lowerRow,bottomRow;

    Scene mainScene;

    String[] template = {"7","8","9","/",
                         "4","5","6","*",
                         "1","2","3","-",
                         "0",".","=","+",

    };

    int num1;

    String currentOperation;

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e){

    //numbers 7-9
    for(int x =0; x<3; x++){

        if(e.getSource() == numButtons[x]){
            String numOne = resultsTextField.getText(); 
            resultsTextField.setText(numOne+template[x]);

        }
     }  

    //numbers 4-6
     for(int x =4; x<7; x++){

        if(e.getSource() == numButtons[x]){
            String numOne = resultsTextField.getText(); 
            resultsTextField.setText(numOne+template[x]);

        }
     }  


     //numbers 1-3
     for(int x =7; x<11; x++){

        if(e.getSource() == numButtons[x]){
            String numOne = resultsTextField.getText(); 
            resultsTextField.setText(numOne+template[x]);

        }
     }  


     // 0 and a decimal
     for(int x =11; x<14; x++){

        if(e.getSource() == numButtons[x]){
            String numOne = resultsTextField.getText(); 
            resultsTextField.setText(numOne+template[x]);

        }
     }  


    // operation

      for(int x =0; x<16; x++)  {
        if(e.getSource() == numButtons[7] || e.getSource() == numButtons[3] ||
           e.getSource() == numButtons[11] || e.getSource() == numButtons[15]){

            String firstNum = resultsTextField.getText(); 
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNum);
            resultsTextField.setText("");
            currentOperation = ((Button) e.getSource()).getText();
        }

      }


     // Equals sign  
      for(int x =14; x<=15; x++){

        if(e.getSource() == numButtons[x]){
            String secondNum = resultsTextField.getText();
            Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNum);

            switch (currentOperation) {
                case "+":
                    num1 = num1 + num2;
                    resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                    break;
                case "-":
                    num1 = num1 - num2;
                    resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                    break;
                case "*":
                    num1 = num1 * num2;
                     resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                    break;
                case "/":
                    num1 = num1 / num2;
                    resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;



            }


          }
        }  
      }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{

        primaryStage.setTitle("Javafx Calc");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();

       GridPane mainPane = new GridPane();

        mainScene = new Scene(mainPane);

       resultsTextField = new TextField();
       resultsTextField.setPrefSize(100, 50);
       mainPane.setPadding(insets);
       mainPane.setConstraints(resultsTextField,0,0);

      //adds buttons 7-9 and division sign to top row and adds top row to 
       mainPane 
       topRow = new HBox(5);
       topRow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       topRow.setPadding(insets);
       numButtons = new Button[17];


         for(int x=0; x < 4; x++){
             numButtons[x] = new Button();
             numButtons[x].setText(template[x]);
             topRow.getChildren().addAll(numButtons[x]);


         }
       mainPane.setConstraints(topRow,0,1);

       //adds buttons 4-6 and multiplication sign to middle row and adds middle 
       row to mainPane
       middleRow = new HBox(5);
       middleRow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       middleRow.setPadding(insets);
       for(int x=4; x < 8; x++){
             numButtons[x] = new Button();
             numButtons[x].setText(template[x]);
             middleRow.getChildren().addAll(numButtons[x]);
       }

       mainPane.setConstraints(middleRow,0,2);

      //adds 1-3 and adds minus sign to lowerRow and adds lower row to mainPane
       lowerRow = new HBox(5);
       lowerRow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       lowerRow.setPadding(insets);
       for(int x=8; x < 12; x++){
             numButtons[x] = new Button();
             numButtons[x].setText(template[x]);
             lowerRow.getChildren().addAll(numButtons[x]);
       }

       mainPane.setConstraints(lowerRow,0,3);

       //adds 0, . , = and + to the bottom row and adds the bottom row to the        
       mainPane
       bottomRow = new HBox(5);
       bottomRow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       bottomRow.setPadding(insets);
       for(int x=12; x < 16; x++){
             numButtons[x] = new Button();
             numButtons[x].setText(template[x]);
             bottomRow.getChildren().addAll(numButtons[x]);
       }

       mainPane.setConstraints(bottomRow,0,4);


    //sets preffered size for all buttons and adds action listeners to each    
    button
       for(int x =0; x < 16; x++){

           numButtons[x].setPrefSize(50,30);
           numButtons[x].setOnAction(this);
       }


       mainPane.getChildren().addAll(resultsTextField,topRow
        ,middleRow,lowerRow,bottomRow);


        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this [simple calculator I made](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4344564).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code comes from that you're handling everything in a one big event handler.

The for loops causes multiple actions to be carried out for a single event, causing multiple issues for you.

You should restructure it so that you add a separate event handler for each specific task so that each handler can do it's specific thing without filtering out everything that it shouldn't do - this is a lot easier to keep track of.

```
public class JavaFxCalc extends Application {

    // All members are the same as your original code

    // public void handle(ActionEvent e) has been removed

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // All setup code is the same up until the for-loop below

        //sets preffered size for all buttons
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            numButtons[x].setPrefSize(50, 30);
        }

        // Add action handlers for the number buttons
        for (int x = 0; x < 14; x++) {
            // We need a final variable for the event handler
            final int index = x;
            if(x == 3 || x == 7 || x == 11) {
                // Skip the operation buttons, we won't hit 15 (+) here since the loop only goes to 13 (.)
                continue;
            }
            // This will create one unique event handler for each button.
            // Since we have the final index variable here we don't need to
            // iterate over the buttons to find the correct template position - we already know it
            numButtons[x].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                    String numOne = resultsTextField.getText();
                    resultsTextField.setText(numOne + template[index]);
                }
            });
        }

        // Add action handlers for the operation buttons
        for (int x : new int[]{3, 7, 11, 15}) {
            numButtons[x].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                    String firstNum = resultsTextField.getText();
                    num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNum);
                    resultsTextField.setText("");
                    currentOperation = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
                }
            });
        }

        // Add action handler for the equals button
        numButtons[14].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                String secondNum = resultsTextField.getText();
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNum);

                switch (currentOperation) {
                    case "+":
                        num1 = num1 + num2;
                        resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        num1 = num1 - num2;
                        resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        num1 = num1 * num2;
                        resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        num1 = num1 / num2;
                        resultsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(resultsTextField, topRow
                , middleRow, lowerRow, bottomRow);

        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```